# How to view all notifications in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

Sometimes, I miss a chrome notification. I want to see all notifications in some window or panel. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly a duplicate. But this is interesting, I made maybe 4-5 google searches but I didn't find that page.

Comment: Maybe I just got lucky, hehe